# How to double imaze size using Sinc function is asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I don’t have much knowledge of sinc function. Please help with this problem.

Thanks

Comment: If you have tried anything then please paste the code in the question

Comment: Something like [this Java code](https://www.nayuki.io/page/sinc-based-image-resampler)?